# different spacing between numbers and signs

Tags: math-mode, spacing

```
$\pi=(-3 \quad -6 \quad +4 \quad -2 \quad +1 \quad +5)$
```

[image]

-3 has a small space and the other numbers have larger spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to see why the spacing differs if you remove the `\quad`   `-3` is a prefix form so the `-` is treated as a `\mathord` and gets no space, but all the others are infix so the `-` is a binary operator so gets space either side, for `3 - 2`.

If your intention is to have a quad space separated list of signed numbers, make them all prefix by

```
$\pi=({-3}\quad {-6} \quad {+4} \quad {-2} \quad {+1} \quad {+5})$
```

[image]

```
$\pi=(-3 - 6  + 4 - 2 + 1 + 5)$


$\pi=({-3} {-6}  {+4}  {-2}  {+1}  {+5})$


$\pi=({-3}\quad {-6} \quad {+4} \quad {-2} \quad {+1} \quad {+5})$


\bye
```